# 複数のソースコードを貼り付けるのに適した方法またはwebサイトはありますか？

Tags: サポート

[c++](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)の初心者でpythonistaだったのですが、
[c++](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)のコードになると、前より余計エラーに悩まされるようになりました。
ここで質問をしたいと思い、コードを大量に貼り付けようとしたら、ガタガタに重くなります。
少し規模が大きくなるだけで、最低でも`Python`の5～6倍はスニペットが増えますね。
コード共有スペースで良いところはありませんか？
`Pastebin`は、１ファイルしか無理ですよね？

バグだらけのコードでも、載せる事が出来る場所はありますか？
やっぱり`GitHub`でしょうか？

全然使ったことが無くてわからないんですが、もしあれば、そこにコードを載せさせてダウンロードしてもらえるようになると思います。回答者様からしても楽だと思います。

自分もこのサイトに長くいますが、`PasteBin`か`GitHub`か、どこかのファイルアップロードサイトかなと思ってはいますが、一応お聞きしたいのです。

例えば、私は個人的なYahooのアップローダでZIPファイル形式でダウンロードしてもらおうかなと思っているのですが、それだと、サイトには全くエラーコードが載せられないし、ずっと公開はしておきたくないので、やっぱり方法論としては駄目だなと感じています。

Comment: 少なくとも、ZIP ファイルでダウンロードする形式は向いていません。なぜなら、(1) ウイルス混入の可能性が高まる、(2) 個人のアップローダはリンク切れで意味が分からなくなる可能性が比較的高い、(3) ZIP にまとめなければいけないような量のソースコードは長すぎで多くの場合もっと短くできる、からです。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PasteBinなどは確かに「1ページに1ファイル」かもしれませんが、共有したいファイルが複数あるならその数だけPasteBinのリンクを作成すればいいだけのような気もします。
(SOでも使用されている、画像共有のimgurでは複数コンテンツをまとめる機能がありますね)

---

問題が起こったコードを丸々掲載するのではなく、出来る限り最小限のコードに削ることも検討してください。読むべきコードが増えればそれだけ回答しようとする人の負担も増えます(理解するのに時間がかかる)。

参考： [ヘルプセンター - 良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> **他の人が問題を再現しやすくする**
>
> ただし、プログラム全体をただコピーすることは避けてください!

---

「重くなる」ページが具体的にどの投稿か分かりませんが、特に**スニペット**はコードを実行可能な状態で貼り付けるので重くなる原因の一つではないでしょうか(単純なテキストであればそこまで負荷にならないはず)。
本当に必要な部分だけをスニペットとして貼り付けるようにしてみてください。
(そもそもc++のコードはスニペットで実行できましたっけ…？)

Answer (score 2):

このような場合はGitHubのGistが適していると思います。
https://gist.github.com/
GistのURLを貼り付ければ大丈夫かと。